# How to unwrap the type of a Promise?

Tags: typescript, promise

Say I have the following code:

```
async promiseOne() {
  return 1
} // => Promise<number>

const promisedOne = promiseOne()

typeof promisedOne // => Promised<number>
```

How would I go about extracting the type of the promise result (in this simplified case a number) as its own type?

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you need to do this instead of using `typeof` after you get the value?

Comment: @FrankModica: I need the type for a class attribute that is null until the promise returns. @ EricKing Everything would need to be wrapped in an async function, which is not an option.

Comment: At runtime, the promise doesn't know what it's going to resolve in the future (imagine waiting for data to come from an AJAX call). So it seems you need TypeScript metadata at runtime. I'm not sure how to accomplish this, but I know Angular's dependency injection uses TypeScript metadata to figure out what class to instantiate and inject. So maybe articles about that will give you ideas on how to accomplish what you need.

Answer (score 418, accepted):

#### TypeScript 4.5

The `Awaited` type is now built in to the language, so you don't need to write one yourself.

```
type T = Awaited<Promise<PromiseLike<number>> // => number
```

#### TypeScript 4.1 through 4.4

You can implement this yourself, with several possible definitions. The simplest is:

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T
// Awaited<Promise<number>> = number
```

Note that this type uses `PromiseLike` rather than `Promise`. This is important to properly handle user-defined awaitable objects.

This uses a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to check if `T` looks like a promise, and unwrap it if it does. However, this will improperly handle `Promise<Promise<string>>`, unwrapping it to `Promise<string>`. Awaiting a promise can never give a second promise, so a better definition is to recursively unwrap promises.

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? Awaited<U> : T
// Awaited<Promise<Promise<number>>> = number
```

The definition used by TypeScript 4.5 ([source](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/feac9eb126e56837d16acb61cd019ce8520db76c/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1492-L1501)) is more complicated than this to cover edge cases that do not apply to most use cases, but it can be dropped in to any TypeScript 4.1+ project.

#### TypeScript 2.8 through 4.0

Before TypeScript 4.1, the language did not have intentional support for recursive type aliases. The simple version shown above will still work, but a recursive solution requires an additional object type to trick the compiler into thinking that that the type is not recursive, and then pulling the property out that we want with an [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U>
  ? { 0: Awaited<U>; 1: U }[U extends PromiseLike<any> ? 0 : 1]
  : T
```

This is officially not supported, but in practice, completely fine.

#### TypeScript before 2.8

Before TypeScript 2.8 this is not directly possible. Unwrapping a promise-like type without the conditional types introduced in 2.8 would require that the generic type be available on the object, so that indexed access types can be used to get the value.

If we limit the scope of the type to a single level of promises, and only accept promises, it is technically possible to do this in 2.8 by using [declaration merging](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html) to add a property to the global `Promise<T>` interface.

```
interface Promise<T> {
    __promiseValue: T
}
type Awaited<T extends Promise<any>> = T["__promiseValue"]

type T = Awaited<Promise<string>> // => string
```

Comment: Nice implementation, this is helping me a lot

Comment: This is beautifull, thank you so much, exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 66):

### Update

As of TypeScript 4.5, we can now use the [`Awaited`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements) keyword, as TmTron wrote in their answer.

I encourage you to view the [source code of `Awaited`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/3b80ddca212959ae5dcf2f48704be627283c6468/src/lib/es5.d.ts#L1518-L1527), which is recursive and has some very interesting edge cases it catches which my solution did not.

### Original

An old question, but I'd like to add my 2 cents. Unwrapping a promise using the `Promise` type is handy, but what I found is that I usually was interested in figuring out the value of a "thenable" object, like what the `await` operator does.

For this, I wrote an `Await<T>` helper, which unwraps promises as well as thenable objects:

```
type Await<T> = T extends {
    then(onfulfilled?: (value: infer U) => unknown): unknown;
} ? U : T;
```

Use it like so:

```
const testPromise = async () => 42
type t1 = Await<ReturnType<typeof testPromise>>
// t1 => number
```

Comment: This is great! I added a small usage example.

Comment: Amazing, just what I was looking for. Thanks!

Comment: Note the existence of type `PromiseLike` which may help simplify your code.

Answer (score 52):

First of all, TypeScript [4.1 release notes](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-1/#recursive-conditional-types) have this snippet:

```
type Awaited<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? Awaited<U> : T;
```

which allows you to resolve things like `const x = (url: string) => fetch(url).then(x => x.json())`, but combining answer from Jon Jaques with comment from ErikE and given that you use version older than 4.1 we get:

```
type Await<T> = T extends PromiseLike<infer U> ? U : T
```

and example:

```
const testPromise = async () => 42
type t1 = Await<ReturnType<typeof testPromise>>
// t1 => number
```

Comment: Any idea how one would write an `AwaitReturnType` helper to skip a step in your example?

Comment: @j_d `type AwaitReturnType<F extends (...args: any) => any> = Await<ReturnType<F>>` usage: `AwaitReturnType<typeof someFunction>`

Answer (score 18):

## Update (typescript >= 4.5)

Since typescript 4.5 we can use `Awaited`: see [Typescript Release
notes](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements)

```js
const promise = new Promise<string>((res, rej) => res('x'))    
type test0 = Awaited<typeof promise>  // string
type test1 = Awaited<Promise<number>> // number
```

[Stackblitz Example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#code/AQ4YwewOwZwF2ABwE4QLYEsYFNgF5gpsB3YABVUxwB55kMoBzAPgApXlsYAaYTgKwCU%20Zny6sA5AA8Jg4aACwAKFDA4AT0S44XOAAZ8wAILEAhhh0ATahq0QAZkkpZso4AHp3wOg0bLVttq6AIyGJuZW1BToLtRQAK5oAEbYyMyinoSJKchAA)

## Original

The [ts-toolbelt](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/index.html) lib has [PromiseOf](https://pirix-gh.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/_any_promiseof_.html)

```js
import {C} from 'ts-toolbelt'

const promise = new Promise<string>((res, rej) => res('x'))    
type test0 = C.PromiseOf<typeof promise>  // string
type test1 = C.PromiseOf<Promise<number>> // number
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `type-fest` if you have access to npm modules:

```js
import {PromiseValue} from 'type-fest';

async promiseOne() {
  return 1
} // => () => Promise<number>

PromiseValue<promiseOne()>
//=> number
```

Answer (score 3):

We can look at the parameters of the Promise's `then` function to infer the type.

```
type PromisedString = Promise<string>;
type AwaitedPromisedString = Parameters<Parameters<PromisedString['then']>[0] & {}>[0];

const promisedString: PromisedString = Promise.resolve('sup');
const x: AwaitedPromisedString = await promisedString;
// assignment succeeds!
const y: string = x;
```

We can generalize into a utility type:

```
type Awaited<T extends Promise<unknown>> = Parameters<Parameters<T['then']>[0] & {}>[0];
const promisedString: Promise<string> = Promise.resolve('sup');
const x: Awaited<typeof promisedString> = await promisedString;
const y: string = x;
```

Let's break this down:

`Promise<string>['then']` a function which accepts a callback. Let's get the parameters of that function.
`Parameters<Promise<string>['then']>[0]` the first parameter of `then`: its callback. this is optional, so we'll need to narrow the union to truthy types only.
`Parameters<Promise<string>['then']>[0] & {}` the callback itself. it's a function; let's grab its parameters.
`Parameters<Parameters<Promise<string>['then']>[0] & {}>[0]` the first parameter of the callback: the value with which the Promise resolves. This is what we were looking for.

Maybe this answer seems redundant in light of the conditional types above, but I'm finding it's useful for resolving Promises inside of JSDoc, where it's impossible (I think) to define new utility types, but *is* possible to use existing ones:

```
/** @param {Parameters<Parameters<ReturnType<import('box2d-wasm')>['then']>[0] & {}>[0]} box2D */
export const demo = box2D => {
};
```

Answer (score 2):

Typescript 3.9 planned on implementing this feature. Unfortunately, it has been moved back and it will probably be in the 4.0 version.

The new type will be called something like `awaited`. It was delayed due to backwards compatibility issues.

[A related discussion on GitHub.](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/37198)

Answer (score 1):

In two steps:

```js
// First, define a type for async functions returning V
type AsyncFunction<V> = (...args: never[]) => PromiseLike<V>

// Second, use the AsyncFunction + infer to define AsyncReturnType
type AsyncReturnType<V> = V extends AsyncFunction<infer U> ? U : V
```

In your case, you can then do:

```js
let foo: AsyncReturnType<typeof promiseOne>
```

If you're just using the `AsyncReturnType` you don't need to export `AsyncFunction`. The `...args` are `never` because you're ignoring them.

This answer is similar to Evan's, which I don't want to change, but eliminates the extra `<ReturnType>` part and (to me) is a bit easier to read.