# How to extract T from Promise<T>

Tags: typescript

I've got use case where async function is declared with followup return type:

```
async function getNumber() {
  const {number} = await API_getNumber();

  return number;
}

export type Return = ReturnType<typeof getNumber>
```

here `Return` is `Promise<number>`. I then need to use this return type, but somehow only get `number` bit from it i.e. without promise. Is this possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 methods:

```
    function promiseOne() {
      return Promise.resolve(1)
    }

    const promisedOne = promiseOne()

    type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : T

    type PromiseOneThenArg = ThenArg<typeof promisedOne> // => number
```

2:

```
function promiseOne() {
  return Promise.resolve(1)
}

type ThenArg<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U :
  T extends (...args: any[]) => Promise<infer U> ? U :
  T

type PromiseOneThenArg = ThenArg<typeof promiseOne> // => number
```

Source: [How to Unwrap Type of a Promise](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-type-of-a-promise?rq=1)