# How to get the return type of async function in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript

Consider we have a function like below

```
const upper = (str: string) : string => string.toUpperCase()
```

We can get the type of the function using `ReturnType`

```
type Test = ReturnType<typeof upper>
```

But now consider we have an async function.

```
const getUserData = async (uid: string): Promise<{name: string, email: string}> => {
   ...
};
```

Now how could we get that type `{name: string, email: string}`

Comment: Wait until the promise is resolved and then check it? `getUserData().then(data => { checkit(data) };`

Comment: I don't know, but a search showed me [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-type-of-a-promise?rq=1), which looks quite relevant

Comment: I find this one even better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50924506/500505

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can create `AsyncReturnType` with [`infer`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-8.html#type-inference-in-conditional-types):

```
type AsyncReturnType<T extends (...args: any) => Promise<any>> =
    T extends (...args: any) => Promise<infer R> ? R : any
```

Test:

```
const getUserData = async (uid: string): Promise<{ name: string, email: string }> => {...};

type T1 = AsyncReturnType<typeof getUserData> // { name: string; email: string; }
```

[Sample](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?ssl=5&ssc=59&pln=4&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBA5gUygVQggTgEQIZWzAXhmwgE8xgYAKAVwEsATALhmnTrDgEoWAFdEAFs6aADwBvGGGyCELNhzgAaGAkHY6AG3lR2nGAF8AfISMBYAFAxrMfkJEIAdOgQQQmgG4JR2MKSNU4gD0AFQwAA6a2MAIABbuDBgwIUGGXADclpZQpOEIMACCZBQASkg06GAAKrneVaoAHlAIYAwQ1I6d2OhwECy+pFymtgLCYgNGJgSWNjD1CE0tbR1dPX3EfkMEJnZj3hwAZkklJgD8MCUw-X5ZFjl5cwCMhIXFwGVQFdW1ovcIIAd4EhUBgcHgjEA)

Comment: For TS v4.5, you can use:
`export type AsyncReturnType<T extends (..._args: any) => Promise<any>> = Awaited<ReturnType<T>>;`

Answer (score 11):

Functions that are marked `async` have a return type of `Promise<T>`

We can use a conditional type to extract the type of the value that the promise will resolve with.

```
export type ValueType<T> =
  T extends Promise<infer U>
    ? U
    : T;
```

Then we can compose this type with ReturnType to obtain the desired result.

```
const getUserData = async (uid: string): Promise<{name: string, email: string}> => {
   ...
};

type UserData = ValueType<ReturnType<typeof getUserData>>;
```

Comment: Thanks man. Your answer is great but I would use accept other one because its a little easy to use.

Comment: No problem. keep in mind that the other answer defaults to any which isn't good for type safety.