# Type of Resolved Promise

Tags: typescript

I would like to use the return type of a function to type an item on an interface like so:

```js
const returnsPromise = async (): Promise<string> => {
  return Promise.resolve('I want the string type and not a Promise')
}

interface Myinterface {
  message: ReturnType<typeof returnsPromise>
}
```

However, message is of type *Promise* instead of *string*.
Can one get the type a promise ought to resolve with?

Comment: I'm not sure I actually understand your question, but you can extract the type out of a Promise like so: `type GetFromPromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never`. Calling that type works like so: `type IsString = GetFromPromise<Promise<string>>`. If that's what your looking for, again it's not clear.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unwrap the type of a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-the-type-of-a-promise)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

TypeScript 4.5 introduced [the `Awaited<T>` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-5.html#the-awaited-type-and-promise-improvements), which evaluates to the type you get if you `await` a value of type `T`.  So you could write:

```
interface Myinterface {
  message: Awaited<ReturnType<typeof returnsPromise>>;
  // (property) Myinterface.message: string
}
```

If you don't have TypeScript 4.5 yet, you can always "un-`Promise`" a type yourself with [conditional type inference](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#inferring-within-conditional-types):

```
type Unpromise<T> = T extends Promise<infer U> ? U : never;

interface Myinterface {
  message: Unpromise<ReturnType<typeof returnsPromise>>;
  // (property) Myinterface.message: string
}
```

They both produce `string` when you pass in `Promise<string>`.  For more complicated types like nested `Promise`s, they produce different results:

```
type APPs = Awaited<Promise<Promise<string>>>; // type APPs = string
type UPPs = Unpromise<Promise<Promise<string>>>; // type UPPs = Promise<string>
```

So it depends on your use cases whether you need to calculate "what a promise resolves with" recursively or not.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.3#code/MYewdgzgLgBATgUygVzpACnEBbAlhBGAXhgEMIBPMYGACgEoAuGTHfBAHmjlzAHMAfMSEBvAFAx4SVGBZY8BAHSIIIADYA3BLQDkASRgB3UmFhQAFoW68+MKBQAOhEwBMYYELFJy2BHfTEAXzExXigEOAAzUmBCAFkKMIjo2JhxSWwECAhSPgRmAEFjXHCXDgAlaTQAFUdOeycQSKkUNAhWBQQBAQBuCRgAegG6BywnOHt6GASkqJiERUzs3PyYa34gkIbCAFUwUd9OaqESapgEAA9wsBcIH06OXkiImB2hAH5XmGYwBC04PqhUzJebTRLAuapdIwJY5PLMPYHB6VVpgWpODjbJotGTteTsbp9SRDEZjCKTMGzFILWErZjrPibLZ1GAFdDoO4kIqkEoIModdgcAUELhQHj8bq9QbDbas9mctZimxiWU7eXEV77fEi4WcXWi8WCQnSuwstUcjX6hkCIA)