# How to retrieve plain object type without surrounding promise in typescript type definition

Tags: javascript, typescript, types

I have a class function `getMockSummaryData` which returns a promise, now getting its return type I can do something like this `type sample = ReturnType<FintechService['getMockSummaryData']>;`, so the return type is something like `Promise { data: somethingElse }`, now my goal is to pick the data type of `data`, I have tried `Pick<sample, 'data'>` or even `Pick<Promise<sample>, 'data'>` but it does not work, it just gives me an error of `TS2344: Type '"data"' does not satisfy the constraint 'keyof Promise { data: SummaryData[]; }>>'.`.

Any help would be highly appreciated here because my googling hasn't been very fruitful.

Comment: `Awaited<sample>`: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype

Comment: Duplicate: [How to unwrap the type of a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-the-type-of-a-promise)