# typescript remove promise from type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

here is my typescript code

```
async function get_string(){
  return "hellow"
}
var the_string=get_string()
```

in the code, the type of `the_string` is `Promise<string>`
I want to somehow to remove the `Promise` from the type of `the_string` so its type is just `string`. maybe using the generics feature of typescript

edit: I have a good use case for this, I am working on a JavaScript interpreter that automatically resolves promises

Comment: I think you're looking for the [`Awaited<Type>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#awaitedtype) utility (e.g. [`Awaited<ReturnType<typeof get_string>>`](https://tsplay.dev/WYK7xN) evaluates to `string` in the type system)

Comment: You don't have any promise on the `get_string()` function. Show us your actual code, so we can understand it better.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to unwrap the type of a Promise?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48011353/how-to-unwrap-the-type-of-a-promise)

Comment: that might work, can i do this by changing just line 4?

Comment: What do you mean by "*a JavaScript interpreter that automatically resolves promises*"? Do you mean that it uses `await` on every single expression?

Comment: yes, but only to the statements that returned a promise @Bergi

Comment: @yigal but `get_string()` is not a statement, it's an expression?

Comment: more specifically, for the right hand side of assignment statements

Comment: I think [that's a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25447289/1048572), asynchronous code should be explicit. But either way, if you are building your own language (as close as it may be to JavaScript/TypeScript), you cannot easily use the TypeScript compiler on it.

Comment: @Bergi that interpreter is actually progressing quite nicely and does have advantages. i will keep you posted when done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution that I came up with is:

```
function unpromise<T>(a:Promise<T>):T{ //generic utility
  return <T>a
}
```

all together:

```
function unpromise<T>(a:Promise<T>):T{ //generic utility
  return <T>a
}
async function  get_string(){
  return "hellow"
}
var the_string=unpromise(get_string())//code change
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want make an interpreter that threats promises as sync values, if may be better to get rid of promises alltogether

The primary source of promises is library async functions
Most of them have sync alternatives - like `fsPromises.readFile` vs `readFileSync`
For those without one, you may implement them yourself, as long as you have an internal function to await Promises:

```
Object.defineProperty(Promise.prototype, 'await', {
  get(this: Promise<any>) {
    return <intrisic await>(this)
  }
})
function fetchSync(...args: Parameters<typeof Fetch>): Awaited<ReturnType<typeof fetch>> {
   return fetch(...args).await
}
```