# Check if request already send

Tags: javascript, typescript, promise

I created 2 functions that send a request to back

```
export const getPopularCategoryList = async (): Promise<Category[]> => {
  const categories = await getOrFetchCategoriesList()

  // my staff
  return categories
}
```

and

```
export const topCategoriesList = async () => {
  let categories = await getOrFetchCategoriesList()
  // staff
  return categories
}
```

The question is that if you call the functions sequentially, they will work correctly.
Like

```
getPopularCategoryList()
setTimeout(() => { topCategoriesList() }, 5000)
```

But I want to make it so that:

If we call function (getOrFetchCategoriesList) and the request has not yet been sent, then we send this request;

If we call function and we have already received a response, then we simply return the received response;

But if we call the function and the request has already been sent, but the response has not yet been received, then we should not send a new request, we should wait for the response to the request and return the result.

```
const getOrFetchCategoriesList = async (): Promise<Category[]> => {
  let response: ElasticsearchAnswer
  if (categories.length) return categories
  if (!categories.length) {
    categoriesLoading = true
    response = await fetchCategoryList()
    categories = response.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
    categoriesLoading = false
    return categories
  } else if (categoriesLoading) {
    // I don't understand what should be here
    categories = await response.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
    return categories
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of awaiting, store a reference to the promise, then await this reference, after awaiting the reference clear the reference.  Now when you call check if reference exists, if it does just return the reference.

Comment: Maybe you are trying to [debounce](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68227965/633183) your query?

Answer (score 1):

I understand, thank's @Keith

```
let request: Promise<ElasticsearchAnswer> | undefined

const getOrFetchCategoriesList = async (): Promise<Category[]> => {
  if (categories.length) return categories

  if (!request) {
    request = fetchCategoryList()
    const elasticsearchAnswer: ElasticsearchAnswer = await request
    categories = await elasticsearchAnswer.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
    return categories
  } else if (request) {
    const elasticsearchAnswer: ElasticsearchAnswer = await request
    categories = await elasticsearchAnswer.hits.hits.map(hit => hit._source)
    return categories
  }

  return categories
}
```